# Alexa SDK V2 High low game not working as it says in tutorial

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, alexa-skills-kit

I am trying to follow the tutorial for the high low game for the alexa sdk v2, but even following the tutorial, I am getting an error.

link to tutorial: 
https://github.com/alexa/skill-sample-nodejs-highlowgame/blob/master/instructions/cli.md

this is the code in the index.js:

```
const Alexa = require('ask-sdk');
const ddbAdapter = require('ask-sdk-dynamodb-persistence-adapter'); // included in ask-sdk
// TODO: The items below this comment need your attention.
const SKILL_NAME = 'High Low Game';
const ddbTableName = 'High-Low-Game';
const FALLBACK_MESSAGE_DURING_GAME = `The ${SKILL_NAME} skill can't help you with that.  Try guessing a number between 0 and 100. `;
const FALLBACK_REPROMPT_DURING_GAME = 'Please guess a number between 0 and 100.';
const FALLBACK_MESSAGE_OUTSIDE_GAME = `The ${SKILL_NAME} skill can't help you with that.  It will come up with a number between 0 and 100 and you try to guess it by saying a number in that range. Would you like to play?`;
const FALLBACK_REPROMPT_OUTSIDE_GAME = 'Say yes to start the game or no to quit.';

const LaunchRequest = {
  canHandle(handlerInput) {
    // launch requests as well as any new session, as games are not saved in progress, which makes
    // no one shots a reasonable idea except for help, and the welcome message provides some help.
    return handlerInput.requestEnvelope.session.new || handlerInput.requestEnvelope.request.type === 'LaunchRequest';
  },
  async handle(handlerInput) {
    const attributesManager = handlerInput.attributesManager;
    const responseBuilder = handlerInput.responseBuilder;
    const attributes = await attributesManager.getPersistentAttributes() || {};
    if (Object.keys(attributes).length === 0) {
      attributes.endedSessionCount = 0;
      attributes.gamesPlayed = 0;
      attributes.gameState = 'ENDED';
    }
    attributesManager.setSessionAttributes(attributes);
    const requestAttributes = handlerInput.attributesManager.getRequestAttributes();
    const gamesPlayed = attributes.gamesPlayed.toString()
    const speechOutput = requestAttributes.t('LAUNCH_MESSAGE', gamesPlayed);
    const reprompt = requestAttributes.t('LAUNCH_REPROMPT');
    return responseBuilder
      .speak(speechOutput)
      .reprompt(reprompt)
      .getResponse();
  },
};
const ExitHandler = {
  canHandle(handlerInput) {
    const request = handlerInput.requestEnvelope.request;
    return request.type === 'IntentRequest'
      && (request.intent.name === 'AMAZON.CancelIntent'
        || request.intent.name === 'AMAZON.StopIntent');
  },
  handle(handlerInput) {
    const requestAttributes = handlerInput.attributesManager.getRequestAttributes();
    return handlerInput.responseBuilder
      .speak(requestAttributes.t('EXIT_MESSAGE'))
      .getResponse();
  },
};
const SessionEndedRequest = {
  canHandle(handlerInput) {
    return handlerInput.requestEnvelope.request.type === 'SessionEndedRequest';
  },
  handle(handlerInput) {
    console.log(`Session ended with reason: ${handlerInput.requestEnvelope.request.reason}`);
    return handlerInput.responseBuilder.getResponse();
  },
};
const HelpIntent = {
  canHandle(handlerInput) {
    const request = handlerInput.requestEnvelope.request;
    return request.type === 'IntentRequest' && request.intent.name === 'AMAZON.HelpIntent';
  },
  handle(handlerInput) {
    const speechOutput = 'I am thinking of a number between zero and one hundred, try to guess it and I will tell you' +
      ' if it is higher or lower.';
    const reprompt = 'Try saying a number.';
    return handlerInput.responseBuilder
      .speak(speechOutput)
      .reprompt(reprompt)
      .getResponse();
  },
};
const YesIntent = {
  canHandle(handlerInput) {
    // only start a new game if yes is said when not playing a game.
    let isCurrentlyPlaying = false;
    const request = handlerInput.requestEnvelope.request;
    const attributesManager = handlerInput.attributesManager;
    const sessionAttributes = attributesManager.getSessionAttributes();
    if (sessionAttributes.gameState &&
      sessionAttributes.gameState === 'STARTED') {
      isCurrentlyPlaying = true;
    }
    return !isCurrentlyPlaying && request.type === 'IntentRequest' && request.intent.name === 'AMAZON.YesIntent';
  },
  handle(handlerInput) {
    const attributesManager = handlerInput.attributesManager;
    const sessionAttributes = attributesManager.getSessionAttributes();
    const requestAttributes = handlerInput.attributesManager.getRequestAttributes();
    sessionAttributes.gameState = 'STARTED';
    sessionAttributes.guessNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * 101);
    return handlerInput.responseBuilder
      .speak(requestAttributes.t('YES_MESSAGE'))
      .reprompt(requestAttributes.t('HELP_REPROMPT'))
      .getResponse();
  },
};
const NoIntent = {
  canHandle(handlerInput) {
    // only treat no as an exit when outside a game
    let isCurrentlyPlaying = false;
    const request = handlerInput.requestEnvelope.request;
    const attributesManager = handlerInput.attributesManager;
    const sessionAttributes = attributesManager.getSessionAttributes();
    if (sessionAttributes.gameState &&
      sessionAttributes.gameState === 'STARTED') {
      isCurrentlyPlaying = true;
    }
    return !isCurrentlyPlaying && request.type === 'IntentRequest' && request.intent.name === 'AMAZON.NoIntent';
  },
  async handle(handlerInput) {
    const attributesManager = handlerInput.attributesManager;
    const responseBuilder = handlerInput.responseBuilder;
    const sessionAttributes = attributesManager.getSessionAttributes();
    const requestAttributes = handlerInput.attributesManager.getRequestAttributes();
    sessionAttributes.endedSessionCount += 1;
    sessionAttributes.gameState = 'ENDED';
    attributesManager.setPersistentAttributes(sessionAttributes);
    await attributesManager.savePersistentAttributes();
    return handlerInput.responseBuilder
      .speak(requestAttributes.t('STOP_MESSAGE'))
      .getResponse();
  },
};
const UnhandledIntent = {
  canHandle() {
    return true;
  },
  handle(handlerInput) {
    const requestAttributes = handlerInput.attributesManager.getRequestAttributes();
    return handlerInput.responseBuilder
      .speak(requestAttributes.t('UNHANDLED_RESPONSE'))
      .reprompt(requestAttributes.t('UNHANDLED_RESPONSE'))
      .getResponse();
  },
};
const NumberGuessIntent = {
  canHandle(handlerInput) {
    // handle numbers only during a game
    let isCurrentlyPlaying = false;
    const request = handlerInput.requestEnvelope.request;
    const attributesManager = handlerInput.attributesManager;
    const sessionAttributes = attributesManager.getSessionAttributes();
    if (sessionAttributes.gameState &&
      sessionAttributes.gameState === 'STARTED') {
      isCurrentlyPlaying = true;
    }
    return isCurrentlyPlaying && request.type === 'IntentRequest' && request.intent.name === 'NumberGuessIntent';
  },
  async handle(handlerInput) {
    const { requestEnvelope, attributesManager, responseBuilder } = handlerInput;
    const guessNum = parseInt(requestEnvelope.request.intent.slots.number.value, 10);
    const sessionAttributes = attributesManager.getSessionAttributes();
    const targetNum = sessionAttributes.guessNumber;
    const requestAttributes = handlerInput.attributesManager.getRequestAttributes();

    if (guessNum > targetNum) {
      return handlerInput.responseBuilder
        .speak(requestAttributes.t('TOO_HIGH_MESSAGE', guessNum.toString()))
        .reprompt(requestAttributes.t('TOO_HIGH_REPROMPT'))
        .getResponse();
    } else if (guessNum < targetNum) {
      return handlerInput.responseBuilder
        .speak(requestAttributes.t('TOO_LOW_MESSAGE', guessNum.toString()))
        .reprompt(requestAttributes.t('TOO_LOW_REPROMPT'))
        .getResponse();
    } else if (guessNum === targetNum) {
      sessionAttributes.gamesPlayed += 1;
      sessionAttributes.gameState = 'ENDED';
      attributesManager.setPersistentAttributes(sessionAttributes);
      await attributesManager.savePersistentAttributes();
      return handlerInput.responseBuilder
        .speak(requestAttributes.t('GUESS_CORRECT_MESSAGE', guessNum.toString()))
        .reprompt(requestAttributes.t('GUESS_CORRECT_REPROMPT'))
        .getResponse();
    }
    return handlerInput.responseBuilder
      .speak(requestAttributes.t('FALLBACK_MESSAGE_DURING_GAME'))
      .reprompt(requestAttributes.t('FALLBACK_REPROMPT_DURING_GAME'))
      .getResponse();
  },
};
const ErrorHandler = {
  canHandle() {
    return true;
  },
  handle(handlerInput, error) {
    console.log(`Error handled: ${error.message}`);
    console.log(`Error stack: ${error.stack}`);
    const requestAttributes = handlerInput.attributesManager.getRequestAttributes();
    return handlerInput.responseBuilder
      .speak(requestAttributes.t('ERROR_MESSAGE'))
      .reprompt(requestAttributes.t('ERROR_MESSAGE'))
      .getResponse();
  },
};
const FallbackHandler = {
  canHandle(handlerInput) {
    // handle fallback intent, yes and no when playing a game
    // for yes and no, will only get here if and not caught by the normal intent handler
    const request = handlerInput.requestEnvelope.request;
    return request.type === 'IntentRequest' &&
      (request.intent.name === 'AMAZON.FallbackIntent' ||
        request.intent.name === 'AMAZON.YesIntent' ||
        request.intent.name === 'AMAZON.NoIntent');
  },
  handle(handlerInput) {
    const attributesManager = handlerInput.attributesManager;
    const sessionAttributes = attributesManager.getSessionAttributes();
    if (sessionAttributes.gameState &&
      sessionAttributes.gameState === 'STARTED') {
      // currently playing
      return handlerInput.responseBuilder
        .speak(requestAttributes.t('FALLBACK_MESSAGE_DURING_GAME'))
        .reprompt(requestAttributes.t('FALLBACK_REPROMPT_DURING_GAME'))
        .getResponse();
    }
    // not playing
    return handlerInput.responseBuilder
      .speak(requestAttributes.t('FALLBACK_MESSAGE_OUTSIDE_GAME'))
      .reprompt(requestAttributes.t('FALLBACK_REPROMPT_OUTSIDE_GAME'))
      .getResponse();
  },
};
const LocalizationInterceptor = {
  process(handlerInput) {
    const localizationClient = i18n.use(sprintf).init({
      lng: handlerInput.requestEnvelope.request.locale,
      resources: languageStrings,
    });
    localizationClient.localize = function localize() {
      const args = arguments;
      const values = [];
      for (let i = 1; i < args.length; i += 1) {
        values.push(args[i]);
      }
      const value = i18n.t(args[0], {
        returnObjects: true,
        postProcess: 'sprintf',
        sprintf: values,
      });
      if (Array.isArray(value)) {
        return value[Math.floor(Math.random() * value.length)];
      }
      return value;
    };
    const attributes = handlerInput.attributesManager.getRequestAttributes();
    attributes.t = function translate(...args) {
      return localizationClient.localize(...args);
    };
  },
};
function getPersistenceAdapter(tableName) {
  // Determines persistence adapter to be used based on environment
  // Note: tableName is only used for DynamoDB Persistence Adapter
  if (process.env.S3_PERSISTENCE_BUCKET) {
    // in Alexa Hosted Environment
    // eslint-disable-next-line global-require
    const s3Adapter = require('ask-sdk-s3-persistence-adapter');
    return new s3Adapter.S3PersistenceAdapter({
      bucketName: process.env.S3_PERSISTENCE_BUCKET,
    });
  }
  // Not in Alexa Hosted Environment
  return new ddbAdapter.DynamoDbPersistenceAdapter({
    tableName: tableName,
    createTable: true,
  });
}
const skillBuilder = Alexa.SkillBuilders.custom();
exports.handler = skillBuilder
  .withPersistenceAdapter(getPersistenceAdapter(ddbTableName))
  .addRequestHandlers(
    LaunchRequest,
    ExitHandler,
    SessionEndedRequest,
    HelpIntent,
    YesIntent,
    NoIntent,
    NumberGuessIntent,
    FallbackHandler,
    UnhandledIntent,
  )
  .addRequestInterceptors(LocalizationInterceptor)
  .addErrorHandlers(ErrorHandler)
  .lambda();
```

This is exactly as it says when the repository is downloaded, and the DynamoDB is set up exactly as they said too, but it still gets an error. When I try to test it, all that comes out is "There was a problem with the requested skill's response".

The errors that I get, and there are a few for a tutorial, in the cloudWatch Management Console are:

[image]

[image]

I am new to Alexa SDK and going back and forth between V1 and V2 is getting really confusing. 
If anyone knows a good tutorial that is maybe not the above link, it would be most appreciated.

If there is anything I can help with please ask. Thank you

Comment: I have updated the original sample to fix these issues! (sent a PR that got approved)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sample is broken as it fails to add a require for i18n in index.js, it's not defining i18next as a dependency in package.json and it's not doing a require of languageStrings.
Add this to the beginning of index.js:

```
const i18n = require('i18next');
const sprintf = require('i18next-sprintf-postprocessor');
const languageStrings = {
  'en' : require('./languages/en')
}
```

and this to the dependencies in your package.json:

```
"i18next": "^10.5.0",
"i18next-sprintf-postprocessor": "^0.2.2"
```

then deploy the back-end again.

Comment: Yes this worked very well. I also had to do the dynamodb configuration different then the tutorial, but this really helped thank you